# Override/Create request parameters in web applications

Tags: jsp, browser, http-request-parameters

I am wondering if there is any app, browser extension and etc that can create/override request parameters in the web application?

For example I have IBM's WebSphere v8.5 locally where I use filter in web.xml that sets user roles/info in init-param and param-name tags so it makes them available as request parameters. But if you want to change values then you need to redeploy your application. You don't lose much time doing that but it is still inconvenient and requires change in deployment descriptor.

So is there any good technique, third party app(free) or browser extension? Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In the subject and tags you said "request parameter", but in the body you said "init parameter".  Can you give a more specific example?  Are you looking for some mechanism to provide configuration to the application that can be dynamically changed?  If yes, I would suggest a [resource environment entry](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_resenventent1.html]) that your filter looks up from JNDI on each request.

Comment: @BrettKail when I set value using init-param I use request.getHeader() to get those values in my jsp pages. Yes, I want to know if I can change them dynamically without redeploying the application. Your link gives me this message: The requested resource is not found: /support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_resenventent1.html]

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me since getHeader should only return request headers, not init-param's.  I made a mistake in the markup.  Here is a corrected link: [resource environment entry](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_resenventent1.html).

Comment: @BrettKail I found solution to this, see the answer. Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found quick solution to this. There is chrome browser extension called [requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa)

It helps me to manipulate requests and headers so I don't have to redeploy my application.

Comment: Requestly Developer here. Just to let you know Requestly is available on Firefox as well. Checkout at http://requestly.in

Comment: @sachinjain024 thank you for creating great extension, it really saves my time. Now I have security concern though, if I am able to override userId/pwd and other headers  locally, then what stops me to use it in dev/prod environments? Is it dangerous? How it works?

Comment: You are using Requestly on your browser So nobody else can see what you are doing with network requests from your browser. Moreover, the rules you define are stored in local storage in your computer and they are not published to any web unless you share them with others So you are safe unless you give the rules, credentials to other users. Feel free to open github issue in case of more questions.

Comment: @sachinjain024 Thank You!